# Аналог jQuery loader

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при клике показалось изображение на 1 секунду и пропало.
В общем есть какая-нибудь функция типа `time`?

Comment: setTimeout или setInterval в зависимости от задач

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть. [setTimeout()](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout) называется.

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно